# Allow vehicles to arrive later than Shipment time window end

Tags: java, algorithm, vehicle-routing, jsprit

As far as I know, applying time windows to Shipment using .setPickupTimeWindow() and .setDeliveryTimeWindow() will impose a hard constraint on solution searching process. If I understand it correctly, it means that these windows should not be broken.

On the other hand, I would like to allow vehicles to pickup / deliver shipments slightly out of time window (let’s say, they can arrive and deliver shipment in 5 minutes after time window ends). While searching for possible solutions, I’ve looked through SoftActivityConstraint class and thought about applying a soft constraint on each inserted job in route to have 0 cost if vehicle is late for less than 5 minutes.

Can I influence vehicles’ arrival and finish times? Can it be implemented using SoftActivityConstraint?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not extend the window by 5 minutes?

Comment: I thought about extending time windows. There is a possibility that driver can be delayed for even longer period of time. However, they still have to deliver shipments, and if they won't fit in extended time window, jobs may become unassigned.

Comment: This is scheduling which you plan earlier. It can not handle delay by the driver or the vehicle broke down. In that case, you can run the scheduler again.